# Label instead of barcode in passbook

Tags: ios, ios6, barcode, passbook, passkit

Is it possible to place a label with text instead of barcode in a Coupon type pass?
Something like this.

[image]

Comment: I would refer you to the [Passbook documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Chapters/Introduction.html).

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist you'd rather not. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the early betas of iOS6, it used to be possible to have barcode type of `PKBarcodeFormatText`, but this never made it through to the production version.

It is now not possible to replace the barcode with text. The best you can do is to add a code and use the altText key to provide a legible string below the barcode.

From the [Passbook Package Format Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/PassKit_Bundle/Chapters/LowerLevel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012026-CH3-SW1) guide:

[image: Passbook Package Format Reference]

Comment: Thank you, i just didn't know, if that beta feature could be used now or not. The altText was a wasy, and now it seems like the only one.